# Texture Paint won't paint on some areas

Tags: texture-painting

The texture paint won't let me paint on the mask. It's super weird, and annoying as I need to paint it. I think it might be an issue with the UV mapping, but I can't figure out what's wrong. This has happened in the past before, but I just ignored it. Please advise.

[image]

EDIT: Here is the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45020

Comment: Do you mind posting the file?

Comment: Please post a portion of your file that demostrate the issue so we could trouble shoot it.

Comment: Just added the file download.

Answer (score 4):

The parts that can't be painted on have inverted normals, so the normals are facing instead of out. Add to that the "Occlude" option in project paint is enabled. To fix this, go into Object mode and select all the faces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to correct the normals, or if they are supposed to be that way, look under the Options tab of the Tool shelf in the Project Paint panel and disable the "Occlude" option.